# how to create a physics body in the shape of an open tin

Tags: ios, iphone, sprite-kit, game-physics, skphysicsbody

how to create a physics body in the shape of an open tin. It should be an edge based body and open from top, as my application needs to collect things in this body

This is my code, but is not working correctly

```
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, 0, 0);
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, 0, 60);
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, 60, 60);
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, 60, 0);

node.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeChainFromPath:path];
```

Answer (score 0):

It was my mistake. here is the working code.

```
CGFloat offsetX = node.frame.size.width / 2;
CGFloat offsetY = node.frame.size.height / 2;
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, 0 - offsetX, 60 - offsetY);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL,  0 - offsetX, 1 - offsetY);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL,  60 - offsetX, 1 - offsetY);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL,  60 - offsetX, 60 - offsetY);
```